# How to reduce huge RAM usage on decoding MIME using Synapse TMimeMess?

Tags: delphi, memory, smtp, mime

I use TMimeMess for decoding incoming e-mails of my SMTP server based
on Synapse.

I discovered that for decoding 50MB MIME message (simple text with
attachments), TMimeMess used 600-800MB of memory.

Decoding code here:

```
FMimeMsg.Header.DecodeHeaders(FMimeMsg.MessagePart.Lines);
FMimeMsg.MessagePart.DecomposeParts;
ExtractPartsFromMess(FMimeMsg.MessagePart);
...
procedure ExtractPartsFromMess(AMimePart: TMimePart);
var i: integer;
begin
  if AMimePart.GetSubPartCount = 0 then
    Begin
      if (AMimePart.PrimaryCode = MP_TEXT) then
        Begin
          AMimePart.DecodePart;          
          FBody.Add(string(ReadStrFromStream(AMimePart.DecodedLines,AMimePart.DecodedLines.Size)));
    end
  else if (AMimePart.PrimaryCode = MP_BINARY) then
    Begin
      if AMimePart.FileName <> '' then
        Begin
          AMimePart.DecodePart;
          AMimePart.DecodedLines.SaveToFile(FPathToIncomingFolder+AMimePart.FileName);
        end;
    end;
end
else
Begin
  for i:=0 to AMimePart.GetSubPartCount-1 do
    Begin
      ExtractPartsFromMess(AMimePart.GetSubPart(i));
    end;
end;
end;
```

Thanks.

Comment: Have you contacted the Synpse authors about this issue?

Comment: I posted this message to synalist-public, but no one did not answer.

Comment: is possible to use indy MIME decoder instead?

Comment: Yes. Indy has `TIdSMTP` and `TIdMessage` components for this purpose. They decode the SMTP data dynamically as it is being downloaded from the server, the data is not pre-cached in memory, and attachments are stored in temp files on the HDD by default.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, that should be an answer, no?

Answer (score 1):

Indy has TIdSMTP and TIdMessage components for this purpose. They decode the SMTP data dynamically as it is being downloaded from the server, the data is not pre-cached in memory, and attachments are stored in temp files on the HDD by default.

You can also try and contact the Synpse authors about this via their email address or website.